# How to set file path in Android JNI?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm building an Android app with C++ library, and I have a problem with sending file path.

I have my JNI function in `jni/processing.cpp` :

```
JNIEXPORT jfloat JNICALL Java_com_my_package_path_getMyFunction
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring param) {
    string str = env->GetStringUTFChars(param, 0);
    string filePath = "src/textfile/";
    return getResult(str, filePath);
}
```

and `getResult()` is a member function of `jni/src/library/myclass.cpp`.

I have several text files under `jni/src/textfiles/`, and I want to send this path to `getResult()` function as a parameter. Since `processing.cpp` is in `jni/` folder, I set path as `src/textfile/`, but it doesn't work. (`getResult()` function can't find the path)

I've been tried `filePath = "../../textfile/"` which is relative path from `jni/src/library/myclass.cpp`, and it also doesn't work.

However, all my other JNI functions (not using file path) are working fine.

Is there anyone who can help? Should I use absolute path? Then, how can I get it?

Comment: Files in random locations of your project including the src/ folder **will not** be available on the device at runtime.  Items packaged under the res/ or assets/ folders may be *available*, but won't actually be literal *files* in a filesystem and so will only be accessible with special Android-unique APIs.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : I'm looking into using `assets/` folder, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution by myself.

According to Chris' comment above, I put my text files into the `assets` folder.

I tried to access `assets` folder from JNI (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317387/how-to-get-file-in-assets-from-android-ndk)), but somewhat it didn't work.

So I read files in Java, and store files again into internal storage. Since we know the `data/data/your_app_package_name/` is the internal storage path, I can read files from JNI.

Here's the code how I read files from `assets` and store to internal storage :

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
    String[] files = null;

    try {
        files = assetManager.list("Files");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(MYLOG, "ERROR : " + e.toString());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        InputStream in = null;
        OutputStream out = null;
        FileOutputStream fileOutStream = null;
        try {
            Log.d(MYLOG, "file names : " + files[i]);

            in = assetManager.open("Files/" + files[i]);
            out = new FileOutputStream(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + files[i]);

            File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), files[i]);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[65536 * 2];
            int read;
            while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            in = null;

            out.flush();
            fileOutStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fileOutStream.write(buffer);
            out.close();
            out = null;
            Log.d(MYLOG, "File Copied in storage");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(MYLOG, "ERROR: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure this is the right solution, but it worked well! :)

Comment: +1 for the smart workaround :D I'm adding an answer with the link to another (better though a bit harder IMO) way...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's actually possible to get the path to the `assets` directory with JNI (I'm not an expert, though): my uninformed opinion is that the Android developers might want us to access the files by proxy anyway, and it might be a good idea doing so to ensure future compatibility.

You can probably get the naked path with a *trick* similar to the one you explained in your answer, and get the assets path from java then pass it to C via JNI.

Regardless, I think that the performance (not to mention space) efficient way to access the files in `Assets` from jni is to use the `AAssetManager`function:

[Android read text file from asset folder using C (ndk)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409125/android-read-text-file-from-asset-folder-using-c-ndk)

and

[Get relative path to file within project in JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606314/get-relative-path-to-file-within-project-in-jni)

Still, +1 to the accepted answer for the ingenuity **:)**